# How to textbox value as a parameter in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, ext.net

How to pass textbox values as parameter in crystal report in asp.net C#?

I want example which shows steps to passparamter
I have tried many examples but no output..
I want as in below link
http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-string-parameter.htm
But no data is displaying

Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help:

```
ReportDocument cryReportDocument = .......;
cryReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("userName", "password");
cryReportDocument.SetParameterValue("parameterName", yourTextBoxName.Text);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryReportDocument;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
  ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

    ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();


    ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    paramField.Name = "@CustomerName";
    paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
    paramFields.Add(paramField);


    CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
    reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
```